# redirection in drupal

Tags: drupal

hi i have made a content type in drupal. in this content type i have added some fields. i want when user submit this form. he will be redirected on a custom page.
right now when user submit this form he remain on this page and an see the success message. i want to redirect the user on a custom page .how can i do this.

Comment: read about [redirect](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#redirect) in Form API

Answer (score 1):

Use the rules module.

Event -> After saving new content

Node -> Content has type
(optional:  User -> has role)

System -> Page redirect